# Import R (android)

Tags: android

I have a problem with my code which refuses to go away. This is the first   half of my code:

---

```
public class SampleGame extends AndroidGame {

public static String map;
boolean firstTimeCreate = true;

@Override
public Screen getInitScreen() {

    if (firstTimeCreate) {
        Assets.load(this);
        firstTimeCreate = false;
    }

    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.map1);
    map = convertStreamToString(is);

    return new SplashLoadingScreen(this);

}
```

---

An error message is generated on the line

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.map1)
```

The error message says I should add the line "import android.R", but when I do this, a second error message is generated which says "map1 cannot be resolved or is not a field." Can someone please give me any suggestions on how to solve this intractable problem?

Comment: Is there any error in your XML?

Comment: this should be removed `import android.R`. Your project will have R.java. So you need not import andorid.R. Check your resource files for errors. R.java will not be generated if you have errors in your resource files.

Comment: What are the contents of the `raw` folder in your project?

Comment: It might be worth using Project -> Clean to regenerate your project's own `R.java` file. On a general not, never import `android.R` - if you need to use the Android resource identifiers, always refer to them in a fully-qualified fashin in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that there is `map1` in `Raw` folder.If it exists,then try `clean/build` your project or close and reopen eclipse.It may be solved.

Comment: Also make sure there are no errors in your other resource files. R.java can't be generated when there are.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your Eclipse android ADT to the latest, restart it.
Im not very good at android but if yours does have an onCreate some where make sure u reference your Resources after it has done the onCreate stuff.